# Access MySql with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I try to connect my MySQL database to the test code of the ASP.NET Core (v2.1) application. I created a sample application and added the `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` nuget package...

Bellow is my code:

```
// Context
public class EntriesContext: DbContext
{
    public EntriesContext(DbContextOptions<EntriesContext> options) : base(options) { }
    public DbSet<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
}

// Controller
[ApiController, Route("api/[controller]")]
public class EntriesController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly EntriesContext _context;

    public EntriesController(EntriesContext context) {
        _context = context;
        _context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        if (_context.Entries.Count() == 0) {
            _context.Entries.Add(new Entry {
                From = "default@from.com", To = "default@to.com",
                Message = "default message", Site = "default site"
            });
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Entry>> GetAll() {
        return _context.Entries.ToList();
    }

// Startup
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddDbContext<EntriesContext>(
    opt => opt.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=mydb;user=myuser;password=mypass"));
  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

the Model is like this:

```
public class Entry
{
    public Entry() {
        this.Date = DateTime.UtcNow
           .Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc))
           .TotalMilliseconds;
    }
    public Entry(long id, string site, string from, string to, string message) : this() {
        this.Id = id;
        this.Site = site;
        this.From = from;
        this.To = to;
        this.Message = message;
    }
```

When I launch the application, I get the following:

[image]

```
System.MissingMethodException
  HResult=0x80131513
  Message=Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommandBuilderFactory..ctor(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics.IDiagnosticsLogger`1<Command>, Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.IRelationalTypeMapper)'.
  Source=MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore
  StackTrace:
   at MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLCommandBuilderFactory..ctor(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, IRelationalTypeMapper typeMapper)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at [...]
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.get_DatabaseCreator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()
   at LoggerApi.Controllers.EntriesController..ctor(EntriesContext context) in C:\MyProjects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Controllers\EntriesController.cs:line 19
   at [...]
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
```

could someone suggest where is the problem here?

Comment: This means that `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLCommandBuilderFactory` called a non-existent EF method in its constructor. Are you using EF Core 2.0 perhaps? The package's NuGet page says it's compatible with .NET Standard 1.6. EF Core 2.0 changed a lot and requires .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Use a different provider, eg [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql). Oracle's support for .NET is a bit ... lukewarm.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with EnsureCreated()? Because afterwards you are checking for entries in the context. It looks redundant or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Yea, Pomelo does a good work and is updated for EF Core 2.1. Oracles driver are pretty outdated, slow when it comes to catch up with current EF Core versions, often very buggy and last but not least my last knowledge on this (EF Core 1.1) is that they are not truly async (sync method wrapped around async apis which still block) which would hurt scalability of your app

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, as the code specifies (CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1) I use the .NET Core 2.1... updated the OP, I mean I use all the latest possible libraries I found at the moment.

Comment: I tried Pomelo, but now at `if (_context.Entries.Count() == 0) {` it says: `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Table 'mydb.entries' doesn't exist'` (I expect the table to be created by the framework)

Comment: I needed to add migrations in order my datatable be created. thanks a lot, and please @PanagiotisKanavos add as answer your comment

Comment: @Vlădel, I tried to add EnsureCreated, because without it trowed the mainly same exception, but it didn't help. Maybe you are right, it does not serve, but there is an(practically the same) exception anyway with, or without it on the same or next lines.

Comment: I had this.  I had to revert back to EF core 2.0.3, and I wait until MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore package support EF core 2.1

Comment: @DanielBlais, why don't you want to use Pomelo? it working for me. Just add migrations

Comment: @Serge, I prefer to wait for official driver.  EF core 2.0 is fine for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Try add package  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/

Version 2.1.2

I worked for me